# Does Lucene / Solr support hypernyms and hyponyms?

Tags: solr, lucene, nlp

For example, houses are buildings, therefore when searching for 'buildings' Lucene would return matches for 'house' as well.  This is not the same as synonyms, searching for 'house' shouldn't match 'building'.

Comment: [This](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/uima/addons/trunk/Lucas/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/lucas/indexer/analysis/HypernymFilter.java) doesn't look that bad.

Comment: Probably preprocess them with Wordnet?

Comment: shouldn't building be weighed less than house for this to work well?
So when people searches tire, the match would be closer to "replacements for vehicles" rather than just "vehicles" so closest match would be better. Just for adding to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply construct a dictionary/hash-table of hypernyms and write a Query Expansion Module having support for hypernyms. To put it simply (1) when the user types in say "Building" in the search Box (2) send your query to your hash table (3) retrieve hypernyms for Building (4) Expand your query something like q=Building+House+Apartment+Villa.